# iOS partial curl transition question?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When using the transition style UIModalTransitionStyleParitalCurl in iOS, how do you change how much is "curled" in the transition?

Answer (score 3):

WrightsCS is (I believe) incorrect.

I've been playing with this recently, and I believe I've discovered how to (indirectly) affect the amount of page curl.

It APPEARS to me that the **left-most** portion of the curl is set to the height of the **highest** control on the view. There appears to be a limit to how high it will go, though. It appears to stop when the right edge of the curl meets the top of the page, regardless of control location.

If the highest control has a Y value of 512 (halfway down a portrait view), the left edge appears halfway down.

YMMV, but my testing appears to confirm this.

As WrightsCS said, though, there's no property to set that **directly** controls this value.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the subview has the influence you've suggested. If you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183079, the second image shows a small table in the bottom right hand corner, but a huge amount of page curl — and the right-edge of the curl is above the top of the page.

Comment: After further testing, it appears that there is a MINIMUM curl height of about half of the view. After that point, your content appears to be able to control the amount of curl.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the amount of curl. There is a modal animation which will curl the entire page up, and then there is the partial curl, which does not have any properties that will allow you to define how much of it to curl.

Comment: but I have used UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl and one time it curled about half way up and one time it went to a different height.

Comment: Simply put, there is no property to allow you to define the "amount" of curl.